# How to perform addition modulo 2 to the power 64

Tags: matlab, math, modulo, block-cipher

I want to perform addition modulo 2 to the power 64 between `p1` and `p2` using MATLAB. Both `p1` and `p2` are of type `uint64`. Is the following code correct?

```
c1 = p1 + p2;
if (c1> 2^64)
    c1 = c1 - 2^64;
end
```

Comment: What data type are `p1` and `p2`? (double? uint64?)

Comment: type of p1 and p2 is uint64

Comment: MATLAB does saturated arithmetic, so if there is overflow in the addition, `c1` will be equal to 2^64-1.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value of variables of `uint64` type is `2^64-1` (in Matlab, `intmax('uint64')`) and when you do an addition operation that exceeds this value (overflow) then the result is `2^64-1`, so your code will not work.

For example:

```matlab
p1 = uint64(2^64-1) - 5;
p2 = uint64(10);
c1 = p1 + p2;
```

The result of `c1` is:

```matlab
>> c1 =

  uint64

   18446744073709551615
```

which is `2^64-1` (and not  `2^64-1 + 5`)

And The result of `c1-p1` is:

```matlab
>> c1-p1

ans =

  uint64

   5
```

But it should have been `10`

#### Workaround:

You can check before the addition if there will be an overflow and if so, calculate the remainder:

```matlab
intmaxDif = intmax('uint64') - p1;
if(p2  > intmaxDif)
    c1 = p2 - intmaxDif - 1;
else
    c1  = p1 + p2;
end
```

This code will perform addition modulo 2 to the power 64 between `p1` and `p2`

Thanks to [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) on the correction.